# Align text and images within a <div>

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML and I'm trying to align my test and images so they are next to each other.

I want the text to be on the left and the image to be on the right.

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px 20px
}

h3.main {
  margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px
}

p.main {
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px
}

p.left {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img.main {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

img.right {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h3 class="main">About Us!</h3>
  <p class="main left">Short Bio</p>
  <img src="img/code.jpg" class="main right">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Use margin-left:70%; or margin-right values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex` and the alignment will be taken care by default and also I have removed unnecessary code to make it simple.

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main,
.left {
  width: 100px;
}

#main img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="text">
    <h3 class="main">About Us!</h3>
    <p class="main left">Short Bio</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="main right">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thats good, but i also want the ```short bio``` text to be under the ```header```